Independent Versioning, Publishing and Reverting of an MFE in a monorepo setup
I'm new to Monorepo and have been evaluating npm workspaces, nx, and lerna for my specific use case or lateral thinking.
I have a shell with header, footer, product, and cart as MFEs, each with their respective versions.
In the context of Lerna, I understand I can publish versions to npm. The question is how to use an older version if the newer version breaks the application.
shell -> 1.0.0
  header -> 1.0.0
  product -> 1.0.0
  cart -> 1.0.0
  footer -> 1.0.0

I developed and implemented some changes in the header and published it as 2.0.0.
How do I go back to version header 1.0.0, and the tool downloads the older version from NPM?
my root package.json
{
  "name": "root",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
}

